# Error in If loop during execution of batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have received the below errors during the execution:

> main.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `(' main.sh: line
>   9:`if %s3% LSS 0 ( '

Please have a look at the sample code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a s1=10
set /a s2=20
set /a Var=0
set /a s3= %s1% - %s2%

if %s3% LSS 0 ( 
    set s3=%s2%-%s1%
    SET /a Var= (%s3%/%s1)*100
) else ( 
    SET /a Var= (%s3%/%s2%)*100
)

pause

if "%Var%" GTR 15 goto failure

:failure

echo %Var%
pause
```

Comment: Whatever this idiocy is you are missing a `/a` at `set s3=%s2%-%s1%`

Comment: And what is your question? Read the [tour] and learn [ask]! Just posting an error message and some code is not enough information!

Comment: I have added it, but still getting the same error

Comment: You named the script main.sh instead of main.bat?

Comment: @SomethingDark no I named the file .bat only. Somehow the script is not executing.

Comment: If it's not a sh script, how is main.sh getting named in the error line along with the line number? Neither one of those features is present in batch. How _exactly_ are you calling this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it, that is, this code get the same result:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set /a "s1=10, s2=20, Var=0, s3= s1 - s2, s3LSS0 = -(s3>>31)"
set /a "s3 = s3LSS0*(s2-s1) + !s3LSS0*s3, Var = (s3 / (s3LSS0*s1 + !s3LSS0*s2) )*100"

if %Var% GTR 15 goto failure
echo Ok: %Var%
pause
goto :EOF

:failure
echo Failure: %Var%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks @Aacini for your approach.